# Is an href=mailto the end of code execution?

Tags: javascript, mailto

I am modifying an old website, and I have run into an issue with javascript. I was hoping somebody could help explain it to me. In this website, there is a `location.href="mailto:..."` statement. After the `mailto`, there is some code that is expected to run. In older versions of this website, this code would run properly, but in my version, the code seems to stop running after the `mailto`. Is there something about this statement I don't understand? Is this normal or does this mean there something wrong with my code?

The website is in `php` language. Here is some sample code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    location.href="mailto:test@example.com";
    document.write("echo")
</script>
```

The `echo` statement won't run, and anything in `php` after the closing script tag won't execute either. Ex: `<?php echo "hi"; ?>`

Comment: Can you add more of the code around this statement, including the full line that's having the problem?

Comment: Context is *everything*.  Please provide us enough code that we can follow what is happening.  The complete element, please, as well as the script code you mentioned, would be great, thanks.

Comment: I've added some sample code.

Comment: The answer to your question is 'no': setting `location.href` causes the browser to stop execution and load the new page.  If you wish to open the mailto link and continue execution, you need to open the link in a new tab, per VFDan's answer, below.

Comment: Note that whether setting `location` stops *JavaScript* execution and whether it stops *PHP* execution are separate questions.  (The answer to the latter is definitely "no".)  It's likely to stop *HTML* processing though, which can look like your PHP stopping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `location.href` *may* halt all JavaScript and HTML processing, depending on the browser (and I wouldn't be suprised if all major browsers handle this the same way).  However, it will never stop *PHP* execution.

It may be hard to tell that your PHP kept running past the point where your JavaScript and HTML stopped, but you can test this by writing to a file: your PHP script will have no trouble creating a file on your server (provided it has the right file permissions), despite it having reached a point where the browser is ignoring its output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `location.href`, put in

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com', '_blank');
```

(Final result: `<script type="text/javascript">window.open('mailto:test@example.com', '_blank'_;document.write("echo")</script>`)

That opens the mailto in a new tab, and allows the rest of your code to continue running.